# C++ socket(...) Как получить свой айпи?

Tags: c++, сокет, ip

У меня есть программа сервер. У меня получается к нему подключаться по всем 3 ip:

`127.0.0.1` локально

`192.168.1.3` роутер

`109.127.85.64` интернет

Я **только UDP** смог сделать чтобы работало.

Как можно **узнать свой айпишник** в сети?(программе надо, я то на 2ip могу узнать). Может через какой-то ресурс можно? Или какой функцией особой. На **линукс** надо.

Comment: [getaddrinfo](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)

Comment: Там на английском и очень много. Мне бы простую функцию int32_t getip(); или на русском хотя бы описание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Элементарного способа сделать это нет. Во-первых нужен, какой-то внешний сервис, который ответит на наш запрос, можно даже тот же 2ip использовать, но лучше найти какой-то попроще и поинтернациональней, например *ipecho.net*. Во-вторых с сервисом нужно будет взаимодействовать по какому-то протоколу, обычно это http и для этого понадобится сторонняя библиотека или программа(вариант ).

Самый простой/топорный способ — это использовать `wget` и `popen(3)` (обработка ошибок опущена):

```
#include <stdio.h>
// ...
char ipaddr[16];
FILE *f = popen ("wget -qO - http://ipecho.net/plain","r");
fnscanf (f, 16, "%s", ipaddr);
fclose (f);
// в ipaddr получаем адрес в обычной точечено-десятичной форме.
```

Минус в данном подходе — зависимость от внешней программы, хотя он же является и плюсом: это позволяет предоставить пользователю возможность настраивать сервис запроса на уровне команды, так что если сторонний сервис перестанет работать, у пользователя будет простой способ поменять его.

Альтернативы/дальнейшие усовершенствования:

- Само собой, можно выбрать любой другой сервис для запроса.
- Можно добавить неблокирующий ввод/вывод.
- Можно использовать использовать библиотеку libcurl или какой-либо другой http клиент по собственному выбору для запросов.
- Если уходить от сервисов на основе http, то есть, например, opendns.com, который при DNS запросе адреса `myip.opendns.com` на один из его серверов, например `resolver1.opendns.com`, возвращает адрес запрашивающего. т.е. если реализовывать всё на низкоуровневых сокетах, достаточно будет одного DNS запроса аналогичного `nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com`.